# Can't connect to <server name> sql server may not be running

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wsus

We have ran into this error, trying to connect to WSUS server:

> **Can't connect to  SQL server may not be running**
>
> **Please verify that SQL server is running and configured correctly on
>   the server.  Contact your network administrator if the problem
>   persists.**

The only thing that changed was the name of the server.  It is Windows 2008 R2 x64 Enterprise edition.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to edit the registry to change from the old name to the new.